# How to navigate in menus of Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How could I know which navigation pattern I have to use in menu of Dwarf Fortress ?

Sometimes, it's <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>
Sometimes, it's <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd>

It's confusing.

Comment: It's a wonderful question, my only real gripe with the game.

Comment: trial and error and memorization. same kind of deal for defining areas: sometimes you get to pick two corners, sometimes you have to resize and  a floating box with uhkm.

Comment: @antony Buildings are `u` `h` `k` `m`, zones and piles are two corners.

Comment: @C. Ross don't burrows let you pick how to define them?

Comment: @Luc welcome to dwarf fortress.

Comment: @C. Ross  We can rezize building ??  I'll try it tonight at home :-)

Comment: @Luc M Some building such as farm plots and walls.

Comment: if you have problems switching between - + and ^ v try changing the key bindings to just two buttons

Comment: ... Very carefully

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a general rule:

When the menu is opened by selecting something on the map (such as by <kbd>q</kbd>uerying a building) you need to navigate the menu with <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.  This is so you can still move the main map cursor with the arrows.

On a full screen menu (like the <kbd>m</kbd>ilitary screen), use the arrow keys to navigate.